# Android SD card path synonims

Tags: java, android, file-io

I have a little bit strange question: this time everything works, but I can't understand why.

AFAIK it's possible to mount more than one sd card. Everything will be mounted to `/mnt` directory. (is it true?)

On my device there is only one sd card which mounted to `/mnt/sdcard`. And in my application I open files from it. I'm using next code:

```
    private void open() {
        // get file extension
        String extension = "";
        int dotIndex = downloadedFile.lastIndexOf('.');
        if (dotIndex != -1) {
            extension = downloadedFile.substring(dotIndex + 1, downloadedFile.length());
        }

        // create an intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri data = Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadedFile));
        String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
        if (type == null || type.length() == 0) {
            // if there is no acceptable mime type
            type = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        intent.setDataAndType(data, type);

        // get the list of the activities which can open the file
        List resolvers = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (resolvers.isEmpty()) {
            (new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setMessage(R.string.AttachmentUnknownFileType)
                    .setNeutralButton(R.string.NeutralButtonText, null)
                    .create()).show();
        } else {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Actually `downloadedFile` variable has value like `file:///sdcard/mydir/myfile.txt`. But the code works. Why? How Android understand what `/sdcard/...` is the same as `/mnt/sdcard/...`?

And main question: what happened if sd card will be mounted to other dir (for exmaple, `/mnt/another-sd/` or even `/media/sd`)? What if more than one sd cards will be mounted: how android understand what card to use?

Thank you for any help! Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

It's simple android configueres the mounting over a settings file on phone boot so if there are mor sdcards Android will simply prefer one of them to set as

> /sdcard/

so when the mount settings change your code is simply useless you can only hope the settings being untouched .
Every company that procuces Android smartphones use the "sdcard" path even custom roms like use it

Comment: what about different paths to the folder? Why path `file:///sdcard/` is the same as `/mnt/sdcard`?